# Hash#merge with default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have a method on `ApplicationController` I call `pagination_params` that uses strong_params to whitelist some keys

```
def pagination_params
  params.permit(:page, :per_page, :after_id)
end
```

I would like to override any values using .merge like so, but I want to use a default value, the ugly workaround I am using for this is:

```
pagination_params.merge(:per_page => pagination_params.fetch(:per_page, DEFAULT_PER_PAGE))
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reverse_merge only merges key/values that don’t already exist in the hash.

Comment: Perfect! Here's [the documentation for reverse_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/reverse_merge), sure enough, it matches my use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFAULT_PARAMS_HASH.merge pagination_params
```

Also, use string as keys in `DEFAULT_PARAMS_HASH` rather than symbol.